# Why are Islands sometimes detected when you combine Chitubox file, but not when you slice models individually?

Tags: print-quality

When making large or complex models I frequently divide them up into smaller parts for printing on my Elegoo Saturn resin printer.

I find it easier to paint the parts separately and then combine them, and it allows me print the top and bottom portions of larger models simultaneously thus reducing print times.

My process typically involves exporting each component as an STL file using Blender, opening the component in Chitubox, and then adding support to it before saving it as a Chitubox project file.

It's less memory intensive to process each component separately, and it makes searching for islands faster as there is less model to deal with.

Once I have saved each individual component as a separate project file I simply open Chitubox and tell it to open all of the project files simultaneously. Chitubox automatically imports them all and combines them into a single new project. This is a feature of the software and doesn't involve any hacks or mods.

I then slice, save and print as normal.

Sometimes though I can import 3 or files that have absolutely no islands when checked separately, but when checked in their combined form there are suddenyl 1 or two islands. This is almost always on the lower layers. Typically right where one of the sub models meets its supports. Usually where I have a flat object that I've tilted at an angle to avoid having too much material in contact with my FEP.

I'm using Chitubox free 1.8.1.

Comment: Could you add an image of the sliced objects to see what you mean, it is difficult to imagine this.

Comment: I've updated the text to make the explanation clearer. All you would see in a picture is a bunch of supports with an island marker.